# Attempting to return option text rather than value as part of loop

Tags: javascript, forms, loops

I am working on some code that loops through a selection of dropdowns to ensure the correct values are selected.  As part of this, I need to return the name of the select and the text of the selected option, as below:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("select");

for(i=0; i < elements.length ; i++){
total_fields += Number(elements[i].value);
document.getElementById("answers_email").value+=elements[i].name +"-"+elements[i].selectedIndex.text;
}
```

The name is returned but the text is 'undefined'.  I have also tried using `elements[i].text` but it yields the same result.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to get your selected text

```
var index = elements[i].selectedIndex;
var text  = elements[i].options[index].text;
```

after that, add it to your 'answers_email' element:

```
document.getElementById("answers_email").value += 
elements[i].name+"-"+text;
```

Comment: Great stuff.  Works perfectly and makes sense.  Thanks for your prompt answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the selected option object inside the `options` array with the `selectedIndex`, and then get its text.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("select");

for(i=0; i < elements.length ; i++){
    var current_select = elements[i];
    var selected_text = current_select.options[current_select.selectedIndex].text;
}
```